# code for equal to '=' in oracle forms calculator?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have multiple buttons 0 to 9 and other calculation methods like plus, minus, etc

There are two display items, `Memory` and `Display`; `Memory` item is hidden.

When click on `1` button then display value 1 in `Display` item. When click on `+` button then store value 1 in `Memory` item.  When click on `=` button then add `Memory` + `Display` values and show answer on `Display` item.

Question is how to code multiple calculation in equal to `=` button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three registers: the button clicked, the display value and the memory value. So the calculation string `2+3=5` looks something like this:

```
button Display Memory 
     2       2
     +       2      2
     3       3      2
     =       5      5
```

As I understand your question, you want to handle a longer calculation, when the user types in several steps without pressing `=`, for instance `2+3+7/4*5=`. There are several ways to do this, but the most intuitive one for the user is to treat the arithmetic operators as having an implicit `=` operation, calculating the running sum and displaying that value.

```
button Display Memory 
     2       2
     +       2      2
     3       3      2
     +       5      5
     7       7      5
     /      12     12
     4       4     12
     *       3      3
     5       5      3
     =      15     15
```

To make this work you need another register item to track the current operator.

```
button Display Memory Operator
     2       2       
     +       2      2        +
     3       3      2        +
     +       5      5        +
     7       7      5        +
     /      12     12        /
     4       4     12        /
     *       3      3        *
     5       5      3        * 
     =      15     15        =
```

So when the user clicks a triggering button you execute something like this:

```
if :operator = '+' then
    :memory := :memory + :display;
elsif :operator = '-' then
    :memory := :memory - :display;
elsif :operator = '/' then
    :memory := :memory / :display;
elsif :operator = '*' then
    :memory := :memory * :display;
end if;
:display := :memory;
:operator := :button_value;
```

You will need to decide how to handle the situation when the user types two operations in a row e.g. `+/`. But probably you need to track previous button press too.

So what is the purpose of `=`? Well, it depends on what the user types next. If they follow `=` with another operator then it's just a subtotal and the sum continues....

```
button Display Memory 
     2       2
     +       2      2
     3       3      2
     =       5      5
     +       2      5  <-- continue with existing sum
     =       7      7
```

... but if they follow it with a number then we're starting a new sum and we reset the memory:

```
button Display Memory 
     2       2
     +       2      2
     3       3      2
     =       5      5
     2       2         <-- start a new sum
     +       2      2
     2       2      2
     =       4      4
```

Comment: How to make operator function

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Thanks worked i created another hidden filed Operator

Answer (score 0):

Create a function like below.

```
create or replace function calculate(p_input VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   v_output VARCHAR2(20);
   missing_expression EXCEPTION;
   invalid_identifier EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(missing_expression, -936);
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(invalid_identifier, -904);
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT '||p_input||' FROM dual' INTO v_output;
   RETURN v_output;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN VALUE_ERROR OR MISSING_EXPRESSION OR INVALID_IDENTIFIER THEN
       RETURN 'ERROR';
END;
/
```

Sample use in SQL,

```
SELECT CAST(CALCULATE('1+2-3+4+5') AS VARCHAR2(20)) output 
  FROM dual;
```

In Oracle forms,

```
:block.io_display_item := CAST(CALCULATE(:block.io_display_item) AS VARCHAR2(20));
```